# How to edit an item which is created using a single form on Angular2?

Tags: forms, angular

I am new to angular2 & I have a form which can add more item to a page (item with `name` & `decription`). This works really well, I can keep on adding new item to my list.

However, each of this item has its own `edit` & `delete`. How can I `edit` and `delete` each of the item using that only 1 form?

```
<form #formExperiencesRef="ngForm">
    <label for="name">name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="fruit [(ngModel)]="formData.name">

    <label for="description">description</label>
    <input id="description" type="text" name="fruit [(ngModel)]="formData.description">

    <button (click)="onSubmit(formExperiencesRef.value)"></button>
</form>
```

This single form is what I use to keep on adding new item. And now I find it hard to `edit` the item that I created using this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often I would advise to go with a reactive form for all it's benefits, but if your form is this simple a template driven approach can be sufficient.

First of all I see problem in your form. Your name attributes are the same for both fields, this will mean that they are evaluated as one and the same. I would actually name them as for how your `formData` object looks like, and then just push the form value as is to the array. I'll just use one way binding here for the sake of the editing of item. Also pass the form object in submit.

How we can edit can be done numerous ways. Here we'll utilize the index of your list (assumingly it's an array).

```html
<form #formExperiencesRef="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formExperiencesRef.value)">
  <input name="name" [ngModel]="formData.name">
  <input name="description" [ngModel]="formData.description">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Your list:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  {{item.name}} <button (click)="edit(item, i)">Edit</button>
</div>
```

And in the TS, we can use `@ViewChild` to reference our form, which I am using to reset the form:

```ts
@ViewChild('formExperiencesRef') formExperiencesRef: NgForm;
```

and your methods for editing and saving a new item:

```ts
formData = {};
items = [];
index = null; // used to store current index value of item (if exists)

edit(item, i) {
  this.index = i;
  this.formData = item;
}

onSubmit(val) {
  // check if index exists, if not it's a new item
  if(this.index == null) { 
    this.items.push(val)    
  } else {
    this.items[this.index] = val;
  }
  // reset index & form
  this.index = null;
  this.formExperiencesRef.reset();  
}
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/ksHp10WwaDg4AQjwDf2d?p=preview

For the future, I really suggest you check out **[reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)**, you have tighter control over your form, handle validations easier and a big,big advantage to me is especially if you are dealing with nested components. Reactive forms can be confusing in the beginning, but it's worth it! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me to understand more about my form. Thanks!!